# Is there any change in reporting implementation of google api client library now that universal analytics is getting deprecated?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4, google-client

I am using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) ([version v2.2.2](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v2.2.2)) in my project for google analytics.

According to [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en) the existing implementation of google analytics is going to get deprecated.

I just want to make sure my existing implementation of google-api-php-client won't be affected by this.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Your existing implementation means code to download report?

Comment: @dikesh yes, Correct